# A graph description language for binary streams (network packets, binary file formats)

Tags: documentation, reverse-engineering, graphviz, file-format, code-documentation

I'm looking for a graph description language to document binary streams like network packets or binary file formats (described in code, then output as a graph).
Something in the same idea that DOT/Graphviz.

Here is an example of the expected result, taken from Wikipedia to describe a network packet.
I'm almost sure I saw such a tool on the internet in the past year, but I cannot find it again. From what I remember the result was quite beautiful, even better than the following example.

[image: A graph describing a network packet]

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of [this](https://tls12.xargs.org/#client-hello/annotated)?

Comment: @andrewJames Tanks for the suggestion, but it's not exactly what I'm thinking about. What I have in mind really renders as boxes, like bordered tables.

Comment: Maybe pikchr (https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md).  Text-based, lower-level than Graphviz, but very scriptable

Comment: @sroush Thanks for the suggestion! I didn't know this tool, it looks quite complete. I will check if it can draw this kind of graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (remembered that I've seen such a things a while ago but couldn't remember where) and after a lot of digging I finally found [Kroki](https://kroki.io/#support) which is an unified API for various textual diagram definition languages.

I think the one I remembered was [packetdiag](http://blockdiag.com/en/nwdiag/packetdiag-examples.html) but the results of [bytefield-svg](https://github.com/Deep-Symmetry/bytefield-svg?tab=readme-ov-file#bytefield-svg) are even prettier.

I continued digging and found the [IETF author resources for digrams](https://authors.ietf.org/diagrams) which pointed me to the [protocol](https://www.luismg.com/protocol/) tool available via in [kramdown-rfc](https://github.com/cabo/kramdown-rfc/wiki/SVG#protocol).